# "em dash" (long dash) not recognized and replaced by strange character during data extract request

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am pulling data from exact target using their Soap API in java, and doing a data extract request. I am able to pull the data, but it looks like ET doesn't handle correctly the "long dash" char. Whenever it is present in the data, it gets converted to this strange character: ñ
Is there any setting for specifying the encoding type before I make the request that can fix this strange behavior, or is it a bug that only ET can deal with?

Thanks,
Erisa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve it myself, after exploring the ET UI, and finding the setting for the encoding.
So I guessed it correctly in my java code and it worked:

```
        extractParam = ExtractParameter.Factory.newInstance();
        extractParam.setName("CharacterEncoding");
        extractParam.setValue("UTF-8");
        extractParameters.add(extractParam);
```